# Templating - printing entry.url throws js error when trying to embed Disqus?

Tags: templating

Default Disqus embed code includes the following:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url =   // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = {{ entry.section }}-{{ entry.id }}; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
```

I am trying to use `this.page.url = {{ entry.url }}`.  This prints the url, but it includes the `http://` and the `:` is throwing an error preventing Disqus from loading.  Is there anyway to template the url without the http://????

Note that the config I am using is straight from Disqus.  The CraftCMS knowledge base article does not include `this-page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your entry.url in quotes so JS reads it as a string.

`this.page.url = '{{entry.url}}`